# ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation Weird First/Last Behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm getting some very strange behavior; `first` and `last` on a relation with 2 elements are returning the same object, whereas `[0]` and `[1]` are behaving as expected:

```
[9] pry(#<ReportSongs>)> performers.class
=> Performer::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation
[10] pry(#<ReportSongs>)> performers.first.name
=> "Ann-Margret"
[11] pry(#<ReportSongs>)> performers[0].name
=> "Elvis Presley"
[12] pry(#<ReportSongs>)> performers.last.name
=> "Ann-Margret"
[13] pry(#<ReportSongs>)> performers[1].name
=> "Ann-Margret"
[14] pry(#<ReportSongs>)> performers.first == performers.last
=> true
[15] pry(#<ReportSongs>)> performers[0] == performers[1]
=> false
```

Why are `first` and `last` returning the same object? I do have other similar objects, but this is the only one exhibiting this behavior.

`performers` is a many to many relationship with `songs`. This `performers` is from:

`performers = a_song.performers`

`ReportSongs` is just the name of the class in which pry has been run. It is a class that produces a report of songs and their performers as a String.

A colleague has suggested that this problem may be related to a caching issue of some kind. When I insert a line like this:

`performers[0]`

before I call `performers.first`, the running code behaves correctly.

Comment: What's exactly the content of `performers`? And what's `ReportSongs`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Thanks, I've added this information and more to the question.

Comment: Can you add the content of `performers` _as it is_? Did you try something like `spring stop`?

Comment: I don't understand your first question. Regarding the 2nd, this code is being executed in the context of a rake task, not the running web app. Does the question still apply?

Comment: I still don't know the exact reason for this, but have narrowed it down somewhat. The problem goes away when I do *any* of the following: 1) reverse the order of the two elements when I add them to the song's performers array, 2) add an explicit order (`performers = song.performers.order(:name)`), 3) call `performers.reload`, 4) use `[0]` and `[-1]` instead of `first` and `last`, since `[]` results in loading the entire array into the cache in its entirety.